# Firebase user A transfer child content to user B. Possible?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Users gets to sign up/log in via email/password authentification on firebase. Done. I am also able to get the current user and also have him write personal info in his child also, game score points are updated to firebase as he progresses. Done.

Now, say I want user A to transfer points to user B. Knowing that user A is the current user. And perhaps user A knows user B's email or userID. How can I make him access/write in user B score points.

I have tried a few methods none worked:
I tried  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().get reference().child("profile/").child(X.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent blah blah blah. 
Where X is B's user ID. Well this returned null.

I read about firebase-admin userRecord ..and after trying to put it in my Gradle and running into many errors I discovered it was for Server side. So not applicable.

I read about making a list of all users but dat didn't seem cool since what happens if I have a million users. It shows all when A only needs B's.

Oh. I'm a mechanical engineer. So please don't refer me to read firebase docs and etc . Most of the terms just confuses me and don't tag this as already asked question believe me I have read them all. Also, I'd very much love it if you could be kind enough to either refer me to a tutorial or explain the codes you have written using A and B as case study.

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to learn how you should post your question. It will help you to get attention and correct help. Welcome to SO. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer at kind of a high level:

I would suggest adding a node that will notify other users of pending transfers. Something like

```
transfers
  transfer_0
    fromUid:  "uid_a"
    toUid:    "uid_b"
    amt:      "100"
  transfer_1
    fromUid:  "uid_c"
    toUid:    "uid_d"
    amt:      "10"
```

All users should add an observer query to that node to watch for any newly added nodes where toUid equals their Uid. In this case childAdded for uid_b.

When user a transfers 100 to user b, it will be written to that node and user b will be notified the transfer node was added and can update their own node, then remove transfer_0.

Likewise, if they are offline and then log in, the childAdded will pull in any new transfers so then their node can be updated and the transfers removed when complete.

Comment: @hazeezadebayo The idea here is that you can make as many transfers as you like. I just used one in my example but I edited it an added another. You could have hundreds of transfers doing it this way and the are all handled as the recipient receives it or logs on.

Comment: Love the way you think bro. You were really awesome.

Comment: If the answer helped, please accept it so it can help others!